# Footer text under poster

Tags: header-footer, posters, baposter

I am using the `baposter` package to create a basic poster and under the last box I'd like to put some normal un-boxed footer text. But I don't really know how to achieve this. `baposter` itself doesn't seem to have a footer component. If I just put the text as is under the last box, nothing is shown and if I put it between `\end{poster}` and `\end{document}`, it is shown on a new page. So what is the easiest way to just put a line of normal footer text under the last box of a `baposter`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a tricky solution. You can write your un-boxed text as a regular `headerbox` but without `header` and `border`. Although it's supposed that all `headerboxes` share options defined in first `poster` parameter, it's possible to change them in `headerbox` options.

```
\documentclass[a0paper,portrait]{baposter}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{poster}
%settings
{background=none,
 borderColor=black,
 textborder=rectangle,
 headerborder=closed,
 headerColorOne=black!30,
 headershade=plain,
 boxshade=none,
 background=none,
}
%Eye Catcher
{}
%Title
{My poster with foottext}
%Author
{Me}
%University Logo
{}

\headerbox{Box1}{name=top,column=0,row=0}{\lipsum[1]}

\headerbox{}%
{name=foottext, column=0, span=3, above=bottom,%
 textborder=none,headerborder=none,boxheaderheight=0pt}{\lipsum[2]}

\headerbox{Box over foot text}{name=second,below=top,above=foottext}{\lipsum[5]}

\headerbox{Box over foot text}%
{name=second, below=top, above=foottext,%
 boxshade=plain,headershape=rounded}{\lipsum[5]}

\end{poster}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I ended up tweaking the `baposter` class with my very modest latex abilities, defining an additional box environment similar to the `headerbox` but removing all the header and drawing stuff from pictures and size computations. But your approach also works (after adding some more options to get rid of shading) and would have been much less painful, didn't know you could override the initial options per box.

Comment: If you're using non-rectangle headers, add `headershape=rectangle` to your foottext box.